# How is the set! Function implemented in clojure

Tags: clojure

In examples, I see

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)
```

and then operations are done. However, what exactly in the function set! And how come it is allowed to mutate *unchecked-math* which is a boolean?

Comment: http://clojure.org/vars#set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain why `set!` works on `*unchecked-math*`:

`*unchecked-math*` is a dynamic Var for which the compiler installs a thread-local binding before it actually starts compiling. It is this thread-local binding that is set to `true` by `(set! *unchecked-math* true)`. `*warn-on-reflection*` works similarly.

The initial value of the compiler's binding is simply whatever is obtained by `deref`ing the Var. In particular, if the compiler is called upon to compile code on a thread which already has its own bindings for the dynamic Vars relevant to the compilation process, the compiler will use the values of those bindings; that is, it will still install its own bindings, but it will use the current values.

Answer (score 3):

`set!` is a special form (i.e. neither a function nor a macro) which sets the value of thread-a local-bound dynamic `Var`, or a Java instance/static field.

`set!` is implemented in Java as part of the core language: [Var.java on GitHub](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L224).

You should read up on `Var` and `set!` on clojure.org, as Ankur points out in his comment: http://clojure.org/vars#set

Comment: How come if I wrote my own (def ^:dynamic *special* 1) dynamic var, using set! throws an error?

Comment: @zcaudate `set!` works on dynamic Vars *with thread-local bindings in place*; try `(binding [special 1] (set! special 2) special)` (NB. this does not change the root binding of `special`, so `(+ (binding [special 1] (set! special 2) special) special)` evaluates to `3`). As explained in my answer, a binding for `*unchecked-math*` is provided by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That clears it up for me. I was thinking of using my own special flag but it'll probably be easier to use an atom as a global var